# CMD operations through Perl

Tags: perl

Trying to run some commands through perl. One of the command requires to press enter in the middle to complete! 
I was first trying with java but failed to do so i thought it's possible in perl but not getting through!

```
$dir = "C:\\bip_autochain\\scripts";
chdir($dir) or die("Can't change to dir \n");

system("lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\\pl\\LCMBiar_Import.property");

sleep(5);
system("\n");
```

The system command highlighted requires to press enter after some time say 5 sec.
My code doesn't serve this purpose.

Comment: try to call "system(qq{start /b "" "lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\\pl\\LCMBiar_Import.property"});"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data from your Perl script to a command launched in a subprocess you need to pipe a filehandle in to the program when launching it. Then you wait the required time and send the data using `print` (or `printf`).

There is one huge caveat. If the external program opens the console terminal directly for input and does not read from stdin (i.e. to prompt for a password) you may not be able to send the data to the program.

For the standard case where the program reads from stdin:

```
$dir = "C:\\bip_autochain\\scripts";
chdir($dir) or die("Can't change to dir \n");

open(CMD, "|lcm_cli.bat -lcmproperty C:\\pl\\LCMBiar_Import.property");
#          ^
#          vertical bar, aka "pipe" symbol

sleep(5);
print CMD "\n";
...
close(CMD); -- when you are done sending data
```

The pipe symbol at the beginning of the command is a special form of `open` that sets up the `CMD` filehandle piped to the command's `stdin`.  This is descibed [in the documentation](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands)

Comment: Thanks for the typo cleanup @MathiasRJensen

Comment: hey, I tried this but it doesn't seems to work. If i run the command directly at command prompt it waits for 5 secs and then asks for password! it proceeds further if i press enter. I need to mimic this scenario

Comment: It is quite likely the program is reading from the console directly. On Linux it might be possible to write to the console, but on Windows you may be out of luck.  This is Windows-API-specific now. It might help to tell us which Perl distribution you are using (Cygwin, ActiveState, something else?)